# How to access document metadata in UIMA?

Tags: metadata, uima

How do you access document meta data such as Created and Modified date or Title etc. using UIMA and JCas?

Comment: Did you find a way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, such information is not available in UIMA.

Some collection reader implementations may store such information in subtypes of DocumentAnnotation or other dedicated annotations. E.g. DKPro Core defines a DocumentMetaData type which derives from DocumentAnnotation and DKPro Core reader components store there the original path/URI of the document and may store a title if available.

Other component collections or collection reader implementations may do similar things.

*Disclosure: I am working on DKPro Core and Apache UIMA*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will see if I can find such meta data. I'm working with the UIMA implementation which comes with Watson Content Analytics, also known as IBM Content Analytics and Watson Explorer.